# SQL - Rank based on scores in separate columns

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-iq

I have the following table:

```
userID|Exam1|Exam2|Exam3|
johnd    10    3      5
```

I would like to rank the scores and place the ranking into new columns as per the below:

```
userID|Exam1|Exam2|Exam3|Rank1|Rank2|Rank3
johnd   10     3     5   Exam1 Exam3 Exam2
```

I am using Sybase IQ.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What if there is a tie?

Comment: The score is actually a 15 digit number, the odds of a tie are very slim. If there is a tie I am happy to take any exam number. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Greg's answer works for three exams.  It doesn't general very well.  An alternative is to do aggregation:

```
select t.userid, t.exam1, t.exam2, t.exam3,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then examname end) as rank1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then examname end) as rank2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then examname end) as rank3
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by userid order by exam desc) as seqnum
      from ((select t.*, exam1 as exam, 'exam1' as examname from t) union all
            (select t.*, exam2 as exam, 'exam2' as examname from t) union all
            (select t.*, exam3 as exam, 'exam3' as examname from t) 
           ) t
     ) t
group by t.userid, t.exam1, t.exam2, t.exam3;
```

This generalizes to more exams more easily -- just add another `union all` in the innermost query and another `max()` in the outermost.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't UNPIVOT in Sybase, you will be forced to use an elaborate set of CASE statements to do it.

```
SELECT Exam_Sort.UserID, Exam_Sort.Exam1, Exam_Sort.Exam2, Exam_Sort.Exam3
, 'Exam' & SUBSTRING(Exam_Sort.ExamOrder,1,1) AS Rank1
, 'Exam' & SUBSTRING(Exam_Sort.ExamOrder,2,1) AS Rank2
, 'Exam' & SUBSTRING(Exam_Sort.ExamOrder,3,1) AS Rank3
FROM
(SELECT table.UserID, table.Exam1, table.Exam2, table.Exam3
, CASE WHEN table.Exam1 >= table.Exam2 THEN
       CASE WHEN table.Exam2 >= table.Exam3 THEN '123'
            ELSE CASE WHEN table.Exam1 >= table.Exam3 THEN '132' ELSE '312' END END
  ELSE CASE WHEN table.Exam2 < table.Exam3 THEN '321'
            ELSE CASE WHEN table.Exam1 >= table.Exam3 THEN '213' ELSE '231' END END
END as [ExamOrder]
FROM table) as Exam_Sort
```